HTML to PDF in react application
i have a problem using html2canvas and jsPDF to save HTML as pdf file. I want to save my html as .pdf in my react application.
import { useContext, useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import html2canvas from "html2canvas";
import jsPDF from "jspdf";
export default function Component() {
const pdfRef = useRef();
async function downloadPDF() {
  const element = pdfRef.current;

  console.log(element.innerHTML); // Sprawdź zawartość elementu
  if (!element.innerHTML) {
    console.log("Element is empty");
    return;
  }
    setTimeout(async () => {
  try {
    console.log("Starting PDF generation");
    const canvas = await html2canvas(element);
    console.log("Canvas generated");
    const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    console.log("Image data generated");
    const pdf = new jsPDF();
    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0);
    pdf.save("download.pdf");
    console.log("PDF generation completed");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error during PDF generation:", error);
  }
}, 1000);};
return (
<>
<div ref={pdfRef}><h1>dupsko</h1></div>
<button onClick={downloadPDF}>generate pdf</button></>
}

Last log is "image data generated" and error:
Error during PDF generation: Error: Incomplete or corrupt PNG file
at new a (png.js:205:1)
at globalThis.webpackHotUpdatemyapp../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.es.min.js.t.processPNG (png_support.js:310:1)
at Object.P (addimage.js:368:1)
at globalThis.webpackHotUpdatemyapp../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.es.min.js.e.addImage (addimage.js:853:1)
at main.bde0929a13abc8746106.hot-update.js:131:13
I was trying with html2pdf.js -> but as result i got empty pdf's. What im doing wrong or waht should I check?
